# Need help troubleshooting copy activity in Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I am trying to copy data from ADLS Gen 2, an excel file , into a database created in sql serverless pool, through copy activity. I am using the auto-create table option, but the pipeline fails to run with the following error :

Operation on target Copy_oe4 failed: ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near 'HEAP'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near 'HEAP'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect syntax near 'HEAP'.,},],'

I tried recreating the datasets and the pipeline as well.

Comment: You cannot create table and copy data to synapse serverless sql pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Synapse SQL Serverless pool**, you cannot create tables. You can create only external tables that reference data stored in external storage, such as Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.
Therefore, you cannot copy the data to serverless SQL pool. This is the reason, you get the error like `A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near 'HEAP'.'` in Azure Synapse Analytics pipeline.

Refer [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-as-select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=powershell) on creating external tables in synapse serverless SQL pool.